# Is there an alternative to BackgroundTask in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Windows Phone 8.0 app that I'm porting to 8.1. In 8.0 I depended a lot on `BackgroundWorker` to execute tasks that I didn't want consuming the UI thread.

I would create the `BackgroundWorker`, define the `DoWork()` delegate and then immediately execute `RunWorkerAsync()`

Now in 8.1 I can't use `BackgroundWorker` anymore. Instead, I need to create Tasks implementing `IBackgroundTask` and use `IBackgroundTrigger` objects run them.

It seems like I need to jump through a lot of hoops just to run code on a different thread. If I want to run a background task immediately to I create a time triggered background task with a new oneShot `TimeTrigger()` with 0 freshness minutes? That seems like a bit of a hack..

Is there an alternative to `BackgroundTask`? Should I be approaching my requirements differently?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To run anything on a different thread, all you need to do is call:

```
Task.Run(delegate() {
    // The work to be executed on the background thread
});
```

You can also `await` this in a non-blocking way, in case you want to do something after the work in the different thread has finished.

`IBackgroundTask` is something completely different. It's used when you want to have some code executed on some event **when the app is not running**. For example, if you want to update the Live Tile every 30 minutes, you would do this using a background task, implementing that interface.

Comment: +1 *BackgroundTask* in WP8.1 RT is similar to *BackgroundAgent* in WP8.0. As for BackgroundWorker and TAP - [here is a good article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html).

Comment: what if I want to update my location to server , when application is suspended or foreground ?